# The image in html file does'n show when I use CocoaHTTPServer to share file

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, image, cocoahttpserver

I am working on a Wi-Fi-Share app with CocoaHTTPServer. But the image of html background is not shown.
The following screenshots are shown something I did in code.

First I creat a instance of HTTPServe and set the "webPath".

[image]

Second I add the html file and image into Xcode .

[image]

Third I set the background of website in my html file.

[image]

Forth I open the url of serve, everything does well but the image don't show.

[image]

Comment: Are you able to access the background image directly?

Comment: @DanielZhang SureDirectly open the page is perfect

Comment: I don't know what could be going on then. I hope you can figure it out.